# Angular doesn't fire off (click) event on part of the div that is blank

Tags: angular, hover, click, partial

I have a div with two rows and part of the second row is shorter. However I want the whole rectangle of the div to be CLICKABLE, just like it is HOVERABLE now. How do I do this? It looks like angular completely ignores the click on the empty area, but acknowledges the hover over the WHOLE area. Strange. Any suggestions guys? Thanks in advance! This is the template:

```
                    <div class="graphItemTitle" (dblclick)="graphItemDoubleClicked(gs)" (click)="graphItemClicked(gs)">
                        <span class='ds-time-dimension'>{{gs.data.time_dimension_name}}</span> <span class='ds-title'>{{gs.data.title}}</span> <br>
                        <span [innerHTML]="gs.data.datasets[0].label | lf2br | safeHtml"></span>
                    </div>
```

And the code is just an `alert("hi");` inside the `graphItemClicked()` method. As I said, it works when I click on a text within the div, but not on the whole rectangle, which is what I actually want.

Comment: can you provide an example stackblitz or something?

Comment: can you add some code ??

Comment: updated the template and the method. It is just a regular (click) handler.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), by removing everything thats got nothing to do with your problem?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht often what you think has NOTHING TO DO with your problem, IS ACTUALLY the problem, so I don' think I should remove much.

Comment: Can you include the styles that are applied to the `graphItemTitle` element?

Comment: I am sharing you opinion, but css got nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Why don't you call the click event on graphItem div instead of graphItemTitle div ?

Comment: That div is the only one that I want clicked.

Comment: @DanielHabenicht I mean, it's unlikely, but if `graphItemTitle` applied `pointer-events: none` and `ds-title` applied `point-events: unset` you could get the behavior. It really is grasping at straws, but technically possible.

Comment: It really got to do with the `pointer-events: none` see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nserht

Comment: You should include the css in your answer then. ;) But please do so in an clear way, for example an extra stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that another piece of html was covering that part of the field. Having removed it, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS property `pointer-events: none` is used it

> instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead. [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

This applys to all elements in the DOM Tree that are beneath it.

The solution is to drop the use of `pointer-events: none` and be more granular about the `(click)` Event Binding or bind to an element above.

Minimal reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nserht